# (flutter) ios how to receive other app's notification data in background?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, flutter

Is any way to receive other app's notification data(such as: title, app, content) and pass to blue tooth?

Can it be implemented?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: so is this mean we can't use software code to retrieve notification content is the app side?

Comment: if i want to retrieve  other's notification, is it possble?

Comment: Definitely not.  It would be a privacy violation